# Mysql Duplicate entry error during new column addition on production database

Tags: mysql, alter-table, auto-increment

I have a MySQL table that has 95929357 records, below is the table schema for the same

```
CREATE TABLE `Friends` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `friendUserId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friendshipStatus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId` (`userId`,`friendUserId`),
  KEY `createdTime` (`createdTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1321597934 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have two questions to ask

**Question 1#**
If it has only 95929357 records, how does the AUTO_INCREMENT increase to 1321597934(Note- entries are inserted by code with default value 0). I also noticed, there is a gap in id(exp- from id 50001124 to new id 50001393)

```
| 50001122 | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 |    116176872 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 | 103802246 |
| 50001123 | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 |    114361519 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 | 116176872 |
| 50001124 | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 |    116176872 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:06 | 114361519 |
| 50001393 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    109233877 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 125715813 |
| 50001394 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    125715813 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 109233877 |
| 50001395 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    105588884 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 125715813 |
| 50001396 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    125715813 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 105588884 |
| 50001397 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    106198652 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 125715813 |
| 50001398 | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 |    125715813 |                0 | NULL    | 2021-09-19 03:33:07 | 106198652 |
```

**Question 2#**
I was trying to add new column with below command

```
ALTER TABLE Friends ADD COLUMN source INT(11) DEFAULT '0';
```

but getting below error while table alter

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '126750770-127846472' for key 'userId'
```

**UPDATE -**

Select result of the above key

```
mysql> select * from Friends where userId = 126750770 AND friendUserId = 127846472;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
| id         | createdTime         | friendUserId | friendshipStatus | remarks | updatedTime         | userId    | source |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
| 1120753287 | 2022-01-27 12:36:12 |    127846472 |                0 | NULL    | 2022-01-27 12:36:12 | 126750770 |      0 |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Friends where userId = 127846472 AND friendUserId = 126750770;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
| id         | createdTime         | friendUserId | friendshipStatus | remarks | updatedTime         | userId    | source |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
| 1120753288 | 2022-01-27 12:36:12 |    126750770 |                0 | NULL    | 2022-01-27 12:36:12 | 127846472 |      0 |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: (1) The gap in autoincremented column values is a norma. AI guarantees uniqueness and not adjacency. Do not pay attention to this. (2) Shown query cannot result in shown error message directly. Check your data consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several causes of gaps in `AUTO_INCREMENT`: `REPLACE`, `INSERT IGNORE`, `ROLLBACK`, IODKU, and others.  Please present some of your insert-like statements; I will provide further details.  I assume you don't know what happened about 2021-09-19 03:33:07.

`Duplicate entry '126750770-127846472'` should not have happened.  This is worrisome as if there was a crash that was not adequately recovered from (unusual).  Does "268" ring any bells?  (That is how many ids are missing *there*.

Did you convert from MyISAM to InnoDB at some point in the past?

I suggest you do some more investigating, starting with

```
SELECT * FROM Friends
    WHERE userId = 126750770
      AND friend = 127846472;
```

That may be only one of several "dup keys".

Let us know what you find out.

**Additional Suggestion**

If the combination `(userId, friendUserId)` is unique, why not get rid of `id` and promote the UNIQUE to `PRIMARY KEY(userId, friendUserId)`?  That would save space and speed up some queries.  There is probably no use for `id` by any other table.

**ALTER**

A long-running `ALTER` on the table may have blocked `INSERTs` long enough for them to timeout.  This might lead to them being `ROLLBACK'd` after the ids had already been assigned.

Comment: I'm using `insert ignore into Friends(userId,createdTime,friendUserId,friendshipStatus,updatedTime) values (?,?,?,?,?) ` query for insertion.

I'm able to select from the above query(In reverse order as well, since I store the values in both orders)

`mysql> select * from Friends where userId = 126750770 AND friendUserId = 127846472;

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Friends where userId = 127846472 AND friendUserId = 126750770;

1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Note: removed the result to save characters

Comment: I added to my Answer

Comment: @ankit.vishen - add the result to your Question.

Comment: result added, please check the update section and I appreciate your suggestion, will try it out.

Comment: Is it possible to get the error because of ongoing queries? since I was doing alter on the production database.

Comment: @ankit.vishen - Yes -- I added to my answer.